# How to enable newer version of php to be default?

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand how to update my php version in my machine. On the CMD I tried getting the version as shown below. I believe this version was installed via XAMPP but now I have uninstalled this program. When I try to get the version again in the CMD it remains 7.2.26!

```
C:\Users\name>php -v
PHP 7.2.26 (cli) (built: Dec 17 2019 15:29:44) ( NTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

I have downloaded a new version, hoping that it would solve it (php v.7.4.8) and added it in `C:\php` directory (it is the only version available) but the cmd will still return version 7.2.26!

Note that when I open the `C:\php\php.exe` and run `phpinfo();` the version is 7.4.8.

My question is how to completely remove php 7.2.26 from my machine. I cannot locate where it is installed!

Comment: Try running `where php`

Comment: hi thanks for your reply! It returns `C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\php.exe` should I delete the entire folder `PHP`? there is only version 7.2 in that folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change System Path variable of your computer which still points to the directory in which old version is installed.

- Goto My Computer
- Right Click, choose Properties
- Select Advance System Settings
- Goto Advanced tab
- Click Environment Variables.
- Double click on Path in the System Variables list
- Remove old folder location from the Variable Value field and add new location.
- Save Settings by clicking OKs

Comment: This solved the problem. Thanks for your reply @gpl! :D